# redirect all page except homepage

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

i want to htaccess redirect all pages to folder called (wp-simply) except home page or / will not redirect , will open the same home page
i have searched a lot but get nothing working

i do this now

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-simply
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-simply/$1  [L,R=301]
```

it redirect all that do not have wp-simply to wp-simply and also redirect the home page to wp-simply
i want it to redirect all except the home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the homepage, you can put the following condition above your RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```

or change your regex pattern to **^(.+)$** to force at least on character in the uri.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$ did not work
please tell me the all code when using  (.+)

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp-simply
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /wp-simply/$1  [L,R=301]

it works , but the home page did not load images and css and js .  what can i do please ?

Comment: They arent loading because your rule redirects them to /folder. You need to exclude them using RewriteConds.